# What is the punishment for watching movies and looking at a girl in islaam?

Tags: sharia

I know that if you see something wrong that is movies or to a (numuharram) girl unintentionally and you move away you'r eye's from that then there is no punishment and it will not be considered as sin.

But What will be the punishment of watching movies and songs, and what is shown in the songs and movies every one knows.

So My question is what will be the punishment for this.

1. In this world from Islamic rules should be given by the islamic governor?
2. After Death on the day of judgement.?

Please give answers with respect to hadith quran and sunnah.

I heard that on the day of judgement the punishment is an iron rod will be heated and inserted in the eyes?

Answer (score 4):

There is no specific punishment for someone who doesn't lower his/her gaze. However, allah said in the Quran:

> And whoever disobeys Allah and His Messenger and transgresses His limits - He will put him into the Fire to abide eternally therein, and he will have a humiliating punishment
>    [Surah 4, Verse 14](http://quran.com/4/14)

Comment: You can't say that there is no specific punishment for watching movies. and seeing wrong things, you might don't know?

Comment: @ali786, I already did my research. besides, why would I answer a question I don't know its answer ?! :-)

Comment: @ali786 there are millions of types of wrongdoings, it is worthless to study what will be the punishment for each wrongdoing. right???

Comment: @suhail yes you are correct but now this sin is getting normal and people are not thinking it as a big sin, out of 100 only 5% people may not have TV's In there home, what about this. what do you thing

Answer (score 0):

There are only a very few punishments told in Ahadees-e-Mubaraka. But why don't you stop yourself if you know  that you are committing sin.

The best way to count the punishment level is..

Feel yourself in front of ALLAH (SWT) and Prophet Muhammad (SAAW). And an 
Angel asks

> "where you not told about this sin?...."

You wouldn't be able to say.. hmmm i didn't know .. or I 'm sorry.bla bla.. but

You'll answer only.,

> "yes i knew this. I was told that it is a sin... But I commit it
>   thinking I will ask for forgiveness after committing."

Then That angel will say..

> "and you didn't asked for forgiveness because you died before that".
>   Now this is the time for punishment..

Feel this!

Comment: Actually I was not asking about its a clear sin or not and about any specific video's my question is for watching at na-muharram intentionally, and what's the punishment in this world and here after.